# What does $g(x_1, x_2)$ mean?

Tags: functions

(high school math, functions, one-to-one, definition)

> We put $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since $x_1=x_2$ always satisfies $f(x_1)=f(x_2), (x_1-x_2)$ will be a factor of $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$

Understood till here.

> Hence we can write $f(x1)-f(x2)= (x_1-x_2)\cdot g(x_1,x_2)$, where $g(x_1,x_2)$ is some function of x1 and x2.

**What does the $g(x_1,x_2)$ signify here, and how can I understand it?**

Rest of the paragraph:

> Now, $g(x_1,x_2)=0$ gives only those solutions, which are of the form $x_1=x_2$, then $f(x)$ is one-one and if $g(x_1-x_2)=0$ gives some solution which is diffrent from $x_1=x_2$ then $f(x)$ is many-one

Apologies for bad phrasing and sentence order.

Comment: It's not clear  (to me) what you are asking here.  One can define a function $g(x_1,x_2)$ to be $\frac {f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$.  Of course, you have to worry about what happens when $x_1=x_2$.  For a polynomial, this works nicely.  If $f(x)=x^2$ then $g(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$, for example.

Comment: Note that if $g(x_1,x_2)=0$ for some values $x_1\neq x_2$ then $f(x_1)-f(x_2)=0$ so $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Thus we see that, in this case, $f$ is not one to one.  That works backwards as well. That's the content of the second passage.

Comment: I have never worked any function with multiple inputs like g(a,b). So I do not understand what it is and how to define it in context of the above definition. 
Your example g(x1,x2) = x1+x2 helps in understanding that it is an operation on both the inputs. But I still can't develop and intuitive understanding of what f(x1)−f(x2)=(x1−x2)⋅g(x1,x2) is trying to show.

Comment: A function with multiple inputs is just like a function with a single input.  Think of it as a machine that takes the values it is handed and returns a single value.  As to the specific question, it's just a definition.  It has the nice feature that "off diagonal" zeroes (meaning solutions to $g(x,y)$ with $x\neq y$) of the function $g$ tell us where $f$ fails to be one to one.  That's something!  Of course, I don't know what more (if anything) your reference plans to do with this function.

Comment: Should say, it's not a great definition in general.  For $x_1\neq x_2$ we have $g(x_1,x_2)=\frac {f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$ as a perfectly good definition.  But, if $f(x)=\sin x$, say, it's not clear what $g(x,x)$ is meant to be.  Again, for a polynomial, you can do the division and get a good answer.  And there are ways to approach the question for other sorts of functions, but it's not obvious what your authors intended.

Comment: Thank you very much, that more or less clears my doubt about this topic :)